# KendoUI Window does not display Ciryllic characters

Tags: unicode, window, kendo-ui

Our ASP.NET MVC application uses the KendoUI window control to display progress messages to the users. It works fine when used in languages with latin characters, but when setting the language of the web application to Russian, where the message should say something like

Составляем рапорт, пожалуйста подождите!

We get what is displayed in the image.

[image: Window title in Russian displaying incorrectly]

Is this an error or are we missing any configuration? I guess it could be something related to Unicode.

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: The string is HTML-encoded.  It has to be decoded first, the way  HttpUtility.HtmlDecode() does it.  Not so clear where that needs to be done.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant What we do is assign a string resource in the view, and it works for any other language (i.e. English, Spanish...). Should we apply HTMLDecode there?

 $("#dialog").kendoWindow({
            width: "@(strLengthHeaderWindowLoader)px",
            height: "150px",
            title: "@Resources.StringResources.GenerateReport",
   actions: ["Close"],
   modal: true,
   close: dialogClose,
  });

Answer (score 2):

Late, but here is one way to do it: use the Raw method from System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper. Here is code for using it as an extension:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace Web.Utils
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static IHtmlString Resource(this HtmlHelper helper, string value)
        {
            return helper.Raw(value.Replace("\"", "\\\""));
        }
    }
}
```

Also quotes are preceded with a slash, in order to be safely used in Telerik control template.

Then extension can be used in code like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Title(Html.Resource(your_string))
```